# Temporary network issue with LXC container

Tags: networking, vmware-esxi, lxc

Good afternoon, colleagues. I have a network availability issue when running the LXC container on a VMware virtual machine. When I turn on the LXC container, about 10-15 minutes, there is no Internet connection and no connection to other virtual machines on the second VMWare host. then suddenly I can ping any website on the Internet without any problems. Ping is always successful for other virtual machines on the same (where this LXC host VM works) VMware host.

Selinux on LXC`s OS is disabled
Selinux on LXC's host is disabled

Version LXC is: **3.0.3**

Network on LXC configure as a bridge

```
IP address LXC-host - 10.10.10.211
3: virtbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:9e:1b:75 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.10.10.211/24 brd 10.10.10.255 scope global dynamic virtbr0
       valid_lft 415487sec preferred_lft 415487sec
    inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fe9e:1b75/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever


IP address LXC-container - 10.10.10.214
8: eth0@if9: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 7e:24:1e:2d:72:74 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 10.10.10.214/24 brd 10.10.10.255 scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 689487sec preferred_lft 689487sec
    inet6 fe80::7c24:1eff:fe2d:7274/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

On LXC host:

**cat /etc/lxc/lxc.conf**

```
lxc.lxcpath = /lxc_storage
lxc.network.type = veth
lxc.network.link = virtbr0
lxc.network.flags = up
```

**cat /lxc_storage/lxc_asterisk/config**

```
lxc.net.0.type = veth
lxc.net.0.flags = up
lxc.net.0.link = virtbr0
lxc.net.0.hwaddr = 7e:24:1e:2d:72:74
lxc.rootfs.path = /lxc_storage/lxc_asterisk/rootfs
lxc.include = /usr/share/lxc/config/common.conf
lxc.arch = x86_64
lxc.uts.name = lxc_asterisk.vivait.lan
lxc.autodev = 1
```

**cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward**

```
1
```

Yes, on VMware host i have enable network promiscuous mode
Please give me advice on what could be the matter?

Comment: journalctl --follow can help when the issue happen

Comment: may be, but it i don't understand how i can use this information.. On  LXC-container log is empty, On LXC-host exists many message "16:28:44 asterisk-host kernel: virtbr0: received packet on ens192 with own address as source address (addr:00:50:56:9e:1b:75, vlan:0)" and then, after the connection is restored, the entries stop appearing..

Comment: I don't understand why you can't journalctl. No matter, you can also record the bridge traffic using tcpdump/wireshark, until the issue happen, maybe you can find a cause in the pcap log.

Comment: check for mac address duplicates in your infrastructure

Comment: @Chaoxiang N. My second comment was not published.. i have same MAC on physical interface and on bridge interface:
`2: ens192: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master virtbr0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:9e:1b:75 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
   
3: virtbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:9e:1b:75 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.10.10.211/24 brd 10.10.10.255 scope global dynamic virtbr0`
And i don't sure that is right

Comment: it is expected that ens192 and virtbr0 have the same mac. check duplicates with other VMs

Comment: I checked for duplicate MAC addresses, but the address is unique..
I also started tcpdump, and when there was no connection, there were many entries in the log:
`16:01:16.797850 ARP, Request who-has gateway tell 10.10.10.214, length 28
16:01:16.798061 ARP, Request who-has gateway tell 10.10.10.214, length 46
16:01:17.800806 ARP, Request who-has gateway tell 10.10.10.214, length 28
16:01:17.801003 ARP, Request who-has gateway tell 10.10.10.214, length 46`

And i notice that i can't ping my machine from gate.

arp -ne from LXC-host
`10.10.10.254   ether   3c:08:f6:a8:e7:7c   C virtbr0`

Comment: If I manually set the MAC address of the router in the ARP table: `arp -s gateway 3c: 08: f6: a8: e7: 7c`, everything starts working right away. I can’t understand what prevents getting a MAC address to the container?